# Error 404: azure storage create a new Block

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload big specific image files (from 1 MB to 5 GB) on the azure storage.

For small files up to 2MB there are no problem for the others I have the "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." answer.

So, I tried to separate the file into serveral blocks  with the following code:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\PublicAccessType;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\Block;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\BlobBlockType;

define('CHUNK_SIZE', 1024*1024); //Block Size = 1MB
$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=....";
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);

$uploadfile =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$content = fopen($uploadfile, "r");
$blob_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$container_name = "natives";

try{
    $counter = 1;
    $blockIds = array();
    while(!feof($content)){ 

        $blockId = str_pad($counter, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $block = new Block();
        $block -> setBlockId(base64_encode($blockId));
        $block -> setType("Uncommitted");
        array_push($blockIds, $block);

        $data = fread($content, CHUNK_SIZE);

        echo " \ n";
        echo "Read ". strlen($data) . "of data from file <br />";
        echo "Uploading block #:". $blockId . "into blob storage. Please wait. <br />";
        $blobRestProxy -> createBlobBlock($container_name, $blob_name, base64_encode($blockIds), $data);

        echo "Uploaded block: ".$blockId . "into blob storage. <br />";

        $counter = $counter + 1;

    }
    echo "Now committing block list. Please wait. <br />";
    $blobRestProxy -> commitBlobBlocks($container_name, $blob_name, $blockIds);
    echo "Blob created successfully. <br />";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Error <br />";
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
    echo "Files : ".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']."<br />";
    echo "content " . $content."<br />";
}
fclose($content);
```

Working with debug mode the problem comes from the

```
$block = new Block();
```

Nevertheless, I include the "Block" classes, so I didn't understand the problem, and I do not know how to have more information about this error. I have only a white page and an error 404, on the developper page (POST).

Comment: Can you check if the container in which you're uploading the blob exists? That could be the 1st cause of your 404 error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the container exist and I can add blob directly without pass by the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried your code and did not get 404 error that you're getting. However I did find an issue with your code. Essentially you would need to change the following line of code:

```
$blobRestProxy -> createBlobBlock($container_name, $blob_name, base64_encode($blockIds), $data);
```

to

```
$blobRestProxy -> createBlobBlock($container_name, $blob_name, base64_encode($blockId), $data);
```

Once I did that, I was able to upload files properly in my storage account.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistaken in your code:

```
$blobRestProxy -> createBlobBlock($container_name, $blob_name, base64_encode($blockIds), $data);
```

Should be:

```
$blobRestProxy -> createBlobBlock($container_name, $blob_name, base64_encode($blockId), $data);
```

Modify `$blockIds` to `$blockId` in your while context.

I had tested your code to upload a tens of MBs size file to blob storage with the modification. It worked well.

By the way, if you get the  Maximum execution time exception, you can set `set_time_limit()` function in PHP script or `max_execution_time`  configuration in **php.ini**.

Answer (score 0):

I made the correction and effectively, it works for files up to 10Mbs. So I try with another file of 62 Mbs and I have the following answer:

```
Read 0 of data from file 
Uploading block #:000001 into blob storage. Please wait. 
Error 
0: 'blob' can't be NULL or empty.
Files : 
content
```

This is due to the size of the files in the $_FILES ? or there are something else ?

Comment: It seemed failed to read the file, you can try to put blob using file directory at first to check Azure storage functions, then to check the upload files.